# PHP ошибка авторизации

Tags: php

Если ставлю условие, то сессию не видит. Хотя авторизацию проходит

```
<?php session_start();?>
<?php if(!empty($_SESSION['login'])) :?>
<?php echo "Добрый день, ".$_SESSION['login'];?>
<br>
<a href="../logout.php">Выйти</a>
<?php else:
    echo 'Войдите в аккаунт';
?>
<?php endif ;?>
```

получение ключа сесси идет из другого файла

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<?php
$login = $_POST["login"];
$password = $_POST["password"];

$sql = $pdo->prepare("SELECT id FROM user WHERE login=:login AND 
password=:password");
$sql->execute(array("login"=>$login, "password"=>$password));
$array=$sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if($array["id"]>0){
    $_SESSION["login"]=$array["login"];
    header("Location:../admin.php");
}else{
    header("Location:../login.php");
}
?>
```

Comment: Т.к. $_SESSION['login'] не содержит ключ login

Comment: он получает ключ из другого файла по идее,

Comment: Внесите изменения в вопрос - этот код из коммента и удалите коммент с кодом

Comment: if($array["id"]>0){ <- тут не срабатывает. У Вас во второй ветке нет $_SESSION["login"]=... header("Location:../login.php");   , а условие  if(!empty($_SESSION['login'])) а в первой вообще на другую страницу уходит

Comment: подскажите как решить эту проблему, я этим занимаюсь совсем не долго и не понимаю, как решить эту проблему

Answer (score 0):

Нашел выход из ситуации.

```
<?php session_start();?>
<?php if(isset($array))) :?>
<?php echo "Добрый день, ".$_SESSION['login'];?>
<br>
<a href="../logout.php">Выйти</a>
<?php else:
    echo 'Войдите в аккаунт';
?>
<?php endif ;?>
```

Но как вывести логин зашедшего человека, всё же не пойму